# How to add "noindex" on opencart filters

Tags: opencart, noindex

on the Analytics i have too much problems with duplicate titles. When i see from where are these duplicate titles i see that i have problem with the filters. For example i have an product with url ribarnik.com/shop/baitrunner-st-fa, but something create a link of the product 
/shop/baitrunner-st-fa?sort=pd.name&order=ASC&limit=100. I dont know how is created this link, but i wanna add all these links (with filters) to be "noindex".

Also i have to all products canonical tag, but google say again that i have duplicated titles.

Please help, really! I have more than 20 000 products and on every product i have between 5-10 duplicated title, so... Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Default opencart uses canonical tags, which does the same as noindex, but it does not stop search engines from visiting those pages.

You can add:

```
Disallow: /*?
```

to robots.txt to prevent future crawlings of URL's with query strings.

You can also remove unwanted URLs from your webmaster tools: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/63758